# Get Specific Product Images based on the label in magento

Tags: image, magento, get

I want to create a nicely crafted featured product slideshow on the homepage. And for that, I want to pick a single unique images of that product. Is it possible get that specific product images based on the label to be shown on the featured product slideshow on the homepage? Or is there any other better way to do that (getting a specific email with certain identifier)?

*thanks before :)*

Comment: yes it is possible. It is easier to help you out if you show the code and describe the situation where you are stuck. Or you can also browse this site faq and try to ask a better question